# by group processing using dplyr - code does not work

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to process by group data using dplyr but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated. Below is a sample of the data. I want to  retain the value for year 2014 and calculate rest of the values for midfs1 using the lag(midfs1) and value. Below is my attempt at the problem.

```
 t3 = t2 %>% 
 group_by(cz,btype) %>%
 mutate( midfs1 = ifelse(year == 2014,midfs1,
 lag(midfs1)*value+lag(midfs1)))
```

t2 data:

```
   cz    btype       year   midfs    value      midfs1
1    College     2014   5.4254  0.007582767 5.4254
1    College     2015   5.4779  0.007582767 NA
1    College     2016   5.5191  0.007582767 NA
1    College     2017   5.5616  0.007582767 NA
1    College     2018   5.6097  0.007582767 NA
1    Grocery     2012   4.8267  0.002697526 NA
1    Grocery     2013   4.8205  0.002697526 NA
1    Grocery     2014   4.8583  0.002697526 4.8583
1    Grocery     2015   4.8966  0.002697526 NA
1    Grocery     2016   4.9556  0.002697526 NA
1    Grocery     2017   5.0258  0.002697526 NA
1    Grocery     2018   5.0982  0.002697526 NA
1    Grocery     2019   5.1514  0.002697526 NA
1    Grocery     2020   5.1976  0.002697526 NA
1    Grocery     2021   5.2338  0.002697526 NA
```

Comment: Do you want by all means to use `dplyr`? If not, `data.table` helps better. However, what is exactly that you want to obtain (*"retain the value and calculate the rest"* are not too much explicative)?

Comment: so, for year 2015 and on, for variable midfs1,  I want to perform the following calculation ( .0075)*5.4254+5.4254 and continue that down by group. I hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you really want to do with your grouping, but try this : `t2 %>% 
  group_by(cz,btype) %>%
  mutate( midfs1 = ifelse(year == 2014,midfs,
                          lag(midfs)*value+lag(midfs)))`

Comment: tried it but no luck, the grouping is to tag the year 2014 for which I have data for different groups. So, all I want to do is apply a growth factor (value) to the midfs1 number and recursively build on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the *compounding growth* problem:

```
t3 <-
  t2 %>% 
  group_by(cz, btype) %>%
  filter(year >= 2014) %>% 
  mutate(my_n = 1:n(),
         midfs2 = ifelse(year == 2014,
                         midfs1,
                         rep(midfs1[1]) * (1 + value) ^ lag(my_n, 1)))

# result

Source: local data frame [13 x 8]
Groups: cz, btype

   cz   btype year  midfs       value midfs1 my_n   midfs2
1   1 College 2014 5.4254 0.007582767 5.4254    1 5.425400
2   1 College 2015 5.4779 0.007582767     NA    2 5.466540
3   1 College 2016 5.5191 0.007582767     NA    3 5.507991
4   1 College 2017 5.5616 0.007582767     NA    4 5.549757
5   1 College 2018 5.6097 0.007582767     NA    5 5.591839
6   1 Grocery 2014 4.8583 0.002697526 4.8583    1 4.858300
7   1 Grocery 2015 4.8966 0.002697526     NA    2 4.871405
8   1 Grocery 2016 4.9556 0.002697526     NA    3 4.884546
9   1 Grocery 2017 5.0258 0.002697526     NA    4 4.897722
10  1 Grocery 2018 5.0982 0.002697526     NA    5 4.910934
11  1 Grocery 2019 5.1514 0.002697526     NA    6 4.924181
12  1 Grocery 2020 5.1976 0.002697526     NA    7 4.937465
13  1 Grocery 2021 5.2338 0.002697526     NA    8 4.950783
```

Comment: Sorry Miha, I did not look at the answer carefully. Your program performs the following calculation for 2016 (.007582767*2*5.4254+5.4254
= 5.5076790881636 but the correct calculation if I follow your way of thinking should be (.007582767^2+.007582767*2+1)*5.4254 =  5.50799103974085851834 . I did not notice this because the answer is close.

Comment: I edited the answer, I added the `cumprod` term as well.

Comment: I don't think you can do that Miha, because the pattern is more complicated than just the cumulative product and sum. I know how to accomplish what I need using loops but I wanted to see if it was possible to do without using loops. I have a feeling this might require some esoteric programming clue to accomplish.

Comment: Have you looked at the results? Are they still wrong? For 2016, the result is identical to what you calculated in previous comment.

Comment: yes, here is a subset of the results from using loops for years 2015-2020.
5.466539544
5.50799104
5.549756853
5.591839366
5.634240982
5.676964118

Comment: I edited the solution again. It should be ok, since I understand now that the problem is about compounding growth.

Comment: Thank you Miha, I have to give it you for having the patience to stick with the problem. I don't believe I would of figured this out on my own. I knew the solution was going to be funky. Once again, thank you I really appreciate it.